# Null Pointer Exception on Accessing CrudRepository Methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, nullpointerexception

I am facing Null Pointer Exception when accessing CrudRepository method inside a class. MessageReceiverListenerImpl. I am not really able to figure out what the issue is.. Since the MessageReceiverListenerImpl instantiated inside ServiceImplI have passed SMSRepo as a parameter instead of Autowiring SMSRepo inside MessageReceiverListenerImpl. I also tried autowiring SMSRepo in MessageReceiverListenerImpl as well. Still I am getting NulPointer exception.

Controller

```
public class SMSController {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    @Autowired
    private smsDatabase SMSRepo;
    @Autowired
    private SMSService smsService;

    @PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> sendSms(@RequestBody SMS newSms)
            throws NotFoundException, DataIntegrityViolationException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String messageRef = smsService.setMessageRef();

        SMS smsToSend = new SMS(newSms);

        Optional<SMS> smsRecord = SMSRepo.findActiveSms(newSms.getTargetMSISDN(),
                messageRef);

        if (!smsRecord.isPresent()) {
            log.info("Sending SMS and updating DB");
            return SMSService.sendSMSAndUpdate(smsToSend, messageRef);
        } else {
            log.info("SMS record exists already with message ref {} for MSISDN {}", messageRef, newSms
                    .getTargetMSISDN());
            SMS smsToUpdate = smsRecord.get();
            smsToUpdate.setExpiryTimestamp(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            SMSRepo.save(smsToUpdate);
            log.info("Existing SMS record expired successfully");
            return SMSService.sendSMSAndUpdate(smsToSend, messageRef);
        }
    }
}
```

Service

```
public interface SMSService {

    String buildAndSendSMS(SMS newSms) throws UnsupportedEncodingException;

    String getSourceMSISDN();

    SMPPSession initBind();

    String setMessageRef();

    void testPrint();

    ResponseEntity<?> sendSMSAndUpdate(SMS smsToSend, String messageRef) throws UnsupportedEncodingException;

    byte[][] splitUnicodeMessage(
            byte[] aMessage, Integer maximumMultipartMessageSegmentSize);

    boolean isEncodeableInGsm0338(String isoString);

//    public String sendShortMessage(ShortMessage shortMessage, String messageRef);
}
```

ServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class SMSServiceImpl implements SMSService {

    **@Autowired**
    **public smsDatabase SMSRepo;**
    
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private SMPPSession session;

    public SMSServiceImpl(
            @Value("${HOST}") String host, @Value("${PORT}") int port,
            @Value("${SYSTEMID}") String systemId, @Value("${PASSWORD}") String password,
            @Value("${SERVERTYPE}") String serverType,
            @Value("${SOURCEMSISDN}") String sourceMSISDN,
            @Value("${SOURCE_ADDR_TON}") byte sourceAddrTON,
            @Value("${DEST_ADDR_TON}") byte destAddrTON,
            @Value("${SOURCE_ADDR_NPI}") byte sourceAddrNPI,
            @Value("${DEST_ADDR_NPI}") byte destAddrNPI,
            @Value("${SERVICE_TYPE}") String serviceType,
            @Value("${DELIVERY_RECEIPT_TYPE}") String deliveryReceiptType) {



        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.systemId = systemId;
        this.password = password;
        this.serverType = serverType;
        this.sourceMSISDN = sourceMSISDN;
        this.sourceAddrTON = sourceAddrTON;
        this.destAddrTON = destAddrTON;
        this.sourceAddrNPI = sourceAddrNPI;
        this.destAddrNPI = destAddrNPI;
        this.serviceType = serviceType;
        this.deliveryReceiptType = deliveryReceiptType;
        this.serviceType = serviceType;

        **this.session = this.initBind();**
    }

public SMPPSession initBind() {

        SMPPSession session = new SMPPSession();

        try {

            log.info("Connecting to SMSC with configuration : host {}, port {}, systemid {}, servertype {}, sourceMSISDN {} ", host, port, systemId, serverType, sourceMSISDN);

            String systemNo = session
                    .connectAndBind(host, port, new BindParameter(BindType.BIND_TRX, systemId, password, serverType, TypeOfNumber.UNKNOWN, NumberingPlanIndicator.UNKNOWN, null));

            log.info("Connected to SMPP Server with system id {}", systemNo);
            ^^session.setMessageReceiverListener(new MessageReceiverListenerImpl(sourceMSISDN, SMSRepo));**
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to connect with SMPP server " + systemId);
            e.printStackTrace();
            session = null;
        }

        return session;

    }
}
```

**MessageReceiverListenerImpl**

This is line 70 causing exception when SMSRepo.finActiveSms is called.

> Optional smsRecord = SMSRepo.findActiveSms(deliverSm
> .getSourceAddr(), destinationAddress
> .substring(sourceMSISDN.length()));

```
public class MessageReceiverListenerImpl implements MessageReceiverListener {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    String sourceMSISDN;
    smsDatabase SMSRepo;

    @Autowired
    public MessageReceiverListenerImpl(String sourceMSISDN, smsDatabase SMSRepo) {
        this.sourceMSISDN = sourceMSISDN;
        this.SMSRepo = SMSRepo;
    }

    @Override
    public DataSmResult onAcceptDataSm(DataSm dataSm, Session source)
            throws ProcessRequestException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAcceptDeliverSm(DeliverSm deliverSm) {

        log.info("Inside message listener...");
        String message = new String(deliverSm
                .getShortMessage(), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        log.info("Message ... {}", message);
        log.info("Service Type {}", deliverSm.getServiceType());

        String destinationAddress = deliverSm.getDestAddress();
        log.info("dest address {}", destinationAddress);

        if (deliverSm.getServiceType().equals("CMT")) {
            // Delivery Status
            log.info("Processing Delivery Receipt for dest : {} source : {} messageref : {}", destinationAddress, deliverSm
                    .getSourceAddr(), destinationAddress
                    .substring(sourceMSISDN.length()));

            String messageID = message
                    .substring(message.indexOf("id:") + 3, message
                            .indexOf(" "));
            String messageStatus = message
                    .substring(message.indexOf("stat:") + 5, message
                            .indexOf(" ", message.indexOf("stat:") + 5));
            **//the below line is 70 causing exception**
            **Optional<SMS> smsRecord = SMSRepo.findActiveSms(deliverSm
                    .getSourceAddr(), destinationAddress
                    .substring(sourceMSISDN.length()));**


            if (smsRecord.isPresent()) {
                SMS updateSms = smsRecord.get();

                updateSms.setMessageId(messageID);
                updateSms.setMessageDeliveryStatus(messageStatus);
                SMSRepo.save(updateSms);

                log.info("Status updated as {} in DB for messageUid {}", messageStatus, updateSms
                        .getMessageUuidRef());

                if (updateSms.getDeliveryReceiptFlag()) {
                    try {
                        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                        SMS result = restTemplate.postForObject(updateSms
                                .getApigatewayCallbackUrl(), updateSms, SMS.class);
                        log.info("Initiated Callback for Delivery Receipt");

                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                }
            } else {
                log.info("SMS Record Not Found for key {} {} {}", deliverSm
                        .getSourceAddr(), messageID, destinationAddress
                        .substring(sourceMSISDN.length()));
            }
        } else if (deliverSm.getServiceType().equals("1001")) {
            // Reply for user
            log.info("Processing Customer Response");

            Optional<SMS> smsRecord = SMSRepo.findActiveSms(deliverSm
                    .getSourceAddr(), destinationAddress
                    .substring(sourceMSISDN.length()));

            if (smsRecord.isPresent()) {

                SMS updateSms = smsRecord.get();
                log.info("SMS record found for DB update as REPLIED for message Uid {}", updateSms
                        .getMessageUuidRef());

                updateSms.setMoMessageReply(message);
                updateSms.setExpiryTimestamp(new Timestamp(System
                        .currentTimeMillis()));
                updateSms.setMessageDeliveryStatus("REPLIED");
                SMSRepo.save(updateSms);

                log.info("Status updated as REPLIED in DB for message Uid {}" + updateSms
                        .getMessageUuidRef());

                try {
                    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                    SMS result = restTemplate.postForObject(updateSms
                            .getApigatewayCallbackUrl(), updateSms, SMS.class);
                    log.info("Initiated Callback for Response");

                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            } else {
                log.info("SMS Record Not Found for key {} {} ", deliverSm
                        .getSourceAddr(), destinationAddress
                        .substring(sourceMSISDN.length()));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Error

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.4.RELEASE)

2021-04-02 23:11:58.293  INFO 16848 --- [           main] com.vodacom.sms.SMSApplication           : Starting SMSApplication on DELOITTE-AP with PID 16848 (started by chand001 in C:\Users\chand001\Documents\MS Dev\bulk sms\microservice-2waysms)
2021-04-02 23:11:58.301  INFO 16848 --- [           main] com.vodacom.sms.SMSApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-04-02 23:12:00.549  INFO 16848 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-04-02 23:12:00.779  INFO 16848 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 196ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-04-02 23:12:02.145  INFO 16848 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2021-04-02 23:12:04.874  INFO 16848 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8090 (http)
2021-04-02 23:12:04.898  INFO 16848 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-04-02 23:12:04.898  INFO 16848 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
2021-04-02 23:12:05.288  INFO 16848 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-04-02 23:12:05.289 DEBUG 16848 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
2021-04-02 23:12:05.289  INFO 16848 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6738 ms
2021-04-02 23:12:06.666  INFO 16848 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : VodaHikari - Starting...
2021-04-02 23:12:07.060  INFO 16848 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : VodaHikari - Start completed.
2021-04-02 23:12:08.866  INFO 16848 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-04-02 23:12:10.082  INFO 16848 --- [           main] com.vodacom.sms.Service.SMSServiceImpl   : Connecting to SMSC with configuration : host xxx, port xxx, systemid xx, servertype cp, sourceMSISDN xxx 
2021-04-02 23:12:10.433  INFO 16848 --- [           main] org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession            : Connected to /xxx
2021-04-02 23:12:10.450  INFO 16848 --- [ession@1aa59698] org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession            : Starting PDUReaderWorker
2021-04-02 23:12:10.810  INFO 16848 --- [           main] org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession            : Other side reports SMPP interface version 34
2021-04-02 23:12:10.810  INFO 16848 --- [           main] org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession            : Changing processor degree to 3
2021-04-02 23:12:10.819  INFO 16848 --- [           main] com.vodacom.sms.Service.SMSServiceImpl   : Connected to SMPP Server with system id 6017
2021-04-02 23:12:10.905  WARN 16848 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-04-02 23:12:11.395  INFO 16848 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-04-02 23:12:11.449 DEBUG 16848 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ModelAttribute, 0 @InitBinder, 1 RequestBodyAdvice, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2021-04-02 23:12:11.666 DEBUG 16848 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 4 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
2021-04-02 23:12:11.746 DEBUG 16848 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Patterns [/webjars/**, /**] in 'resourceHandlerMapping'
2021-04-02 23:12:11.784 DEBUG 16848 --- [           main] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : ControllerAdvice beans: 1 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2021-04-02 23:12:13.021  INFO 16848 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8090 (http) with context path ''
2021-04-02 23:12:13.023  INFO 16848 --- [           main] com.vodacom.sms.SMSApplication           : Started SMSApplication in 15.802 seconds (JVM running for 17.669)
2021-04-02 23:12:30.126  INFO 16848 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-04-02 23:12:30.126  INFO 16848 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-04-02 23:12:30.126 DEBUG 16848 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2021-04-02 23:12:30.144 DEBUG 16848 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2021-04-02 23:12:30.144  INFO 16848 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 18 ms
2021-04-02 23:12:30.172 DEBUG 16848 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/vodacom/sms/", parameters={}
2021-04-02 23:12:30.187 DEBUG 16848 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.vodacom.sms.Controller.SMSController#sendSms(SMS)
2021-04-02 23:12:30.450 DEBUG 16848 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Read "application/json;charset=UTF-8" to [com.vodacom.sms.Model.SMS@60278f1]
2021-04-02 23:12:30.951  INFO 16848 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] c.vodacom.sms.Controller.SMSController   : Sending SMS and updating DB
2021-04-02 23:12:30.953  INFO 16848 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] com.vodacom.sms.Service.SMSServiceImpl   : determining if it is GSM or UCS2...
2021-04-02 23:12:30.954  INFO 16848 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] com.vodacom.sms.Service.SMSServiceImpl   : Encoding in GSM...
2021-04-02 23:12:30.955  INFO 16848 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] com.vodacom.sms.Service.SMSServiceImpl   : Check if message needs splitting and set required sending parameters
2021-04-02 23:12:30.956  INFO 16848 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] com.vodacom.sms.Service.SMSServiceImpl   : Sending message -> {}test message
2021-04-02 23:12:30.956  INFO 16848 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] com.vodacom.sms.Service.SMSServiceImpl   : Message is 12 characters long and will be sent as 1 messages with encoding ALPHA_DEFAULT
2021-04-02 23:12:31.576  INFO 16848 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] com.vodacom.sms.Service.SMSServiceImpl   : SMS sent and DB updated
2021-04-02 23:12:31.630 DEBUG 16848 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2021-04-02 23:12:31.631 DEBUG 16848 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [com.vodacom.sms.Model.SMS@156ffd37]
2021-04-02 23:12:31.685 DEBUG 16848 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 201 CREATED
2021-04-02 23:12:35.916  INFO 16848 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.v.s.S.MessageReceiverListenerImpl      : Inside message listener...
2021-04-02 23:12:35.916  INFO 16848 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.v.s.S.MessageReceiverListenerImpl      : Message ... id:
2021-04-02 23:12:35.916  INFO 16848 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.v.s.S.MessageReceiverListenerImpl      : Service Type CMT
2021-04-02 23:12:35.917  INFO 16848 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.v.s.S.MessageReceiverListenerImpl      : dest address xxxx
2021-04-02 23:12:35.917  INFO 16848 --- [pool-1-thread-1] c.v.s.S.MessageReceiverListenerImpl      : Processing Delivery Receipt for dest : xxx source : xxx messageref : xxx
2021-04-02 23:12:35.917 ERROR 16848 --- [pool-1-thread-1] org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession            : Invalid runtime exception thrown when processing deliver_sm

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.vodacom.sms.Service.MessageReceiverListenerImpl.onAcceptDeliverSm(MessageReceiverListenerImpl.java:70) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.fireAcceptDeliverSm(SMPPSession.java:461) ~[jsmpp-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.access$300(SMPPSession.java:94) ~[jsmpp-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession$ResponseHandlerImpl.processDeliverSm(SMPPSession.java:480) ~[jsmpp-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
    at org.jsmpp.session.state.SMPPSessionBoundRX.processDeliverSm0(SMPPSessionBoundRX.java:109) ~[jsmpp-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
    at org.jsmpp.session.state.SMPPSessionBoundTRX.processDeliverSm(SMPPSessionBoundTRX.java:42) ~[jsmpp-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
    at org.jsmpp.session.PDUProcessTask.run(PDUProcessTask.java:91) ~[jsmpp-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]

2021-04-02 23:12:35.918 ERROR 16848 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.j.session.state.SMPPSessionBoundRX     : Failed processing deliver_sm

org.jsmpp.extra.ProcessRequestException: Invalid runtime exception thrown when processing deliver_sm
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession$ResponseHandlerImpl.processDeliverSm(SMPPSession.java:486) ~[jsmpp-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
    at org.jsmpp.session.state.SMPPSessionBoundRX.processDeliverSm0(SMPPSessionBoundRX.java:109) ~[jsmpp-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
    at org.jsmpp.session.state.SMPPSessionBoundTRX.processDeliverSm(SMPPSessionBoundTRX.java:42) ~[jsmpp-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
    at org.jsmpp.session.PDUProcessTask.run(PDUProcessTask.java:91) ~[jsmpp-2.3.6.jar:2.3.6]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Is that a ful stacktrace? If not, then can you please provide a full stacktrace.

Comment: `org.jsmpp.extra.ProcessRequestException: Invalid runtime exception thrown when processing deliver_sm` this seems to be causing issue.

Comment: It would be easier to guess what's the problem if you mark the `70` line in `MessageReceiverListenerImpl` class with some comment.

Comment: @AndreiYusupau I have added a comment to mark line 70 inMessageReceiverListenerImpl.. Optional<SMS> smsRecord = SMSRepo.findActiveSms(deliverSm
                    .getSourceAddr(), destinationAddress
                    .substring(sourceMSISDN.length()));

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri I have provided the complete stacktrace now.

Comment: First of all class name should be in camel case, `smsDatabase` looks like a variable and `SMSRepo` a class name. Also add the `smsDatabase` class to the question, how it looks like?

Comment: Your `SMSRepo` is `null`, possibly naming issue as @code_mechanic mentioned above.